# Ruby equivalent of PHP's "get_defined_vars" function?

Tags: ruby, equivalent

I've written a little while loop program in ruby and I can see the RAM it use is visibly growing after each loop !

So I trayed to :

- Use `GC.Start` at the end of the loop but it has no effects
- Change all inside loop variable to Global but memory used still raise after each loop.

So is there any equivalent of PHP's "`get_defined_vars`" function in Ruby in order to view wich make my used memory growing like that ?

Comment: please post the code on https://gist.github.com/ if it is too large for the question.

Comment: `GC.stress=true` seems to be the only way to drain RAM but it slow the script a lot

Comment: @cz3ch: where's the gist hyperlink?

Comment: @Andrew Because in fact this question was properly answered :-/
Actually the source code and the real problem I got in it refer to another question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Kernel.local_variables`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001391) seems to be the closest match

Comment: Yep sure the closest one but local_variables nor global_variable version can debug this probleme because only one version of them are stored so I really don't understend where is the probleme here. I've posted the source if you want to take a look on it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org/.

It's a quite exhaustive tool.

According to the homepage:

> Ruby prof can measure a number of different parameters, including
>   call times, memory usage and object allocations.

**edit**:
Seems it's been more recently updated on its github page: https://github.com/rdp/ruby-prof

Comment: Many thanks for this tool but I can't find where is the mistake. I've posted the source if you can take a look on it.